# Chat progressive web application, open source, messages viewable offline

Tags: open-source, offline, chat, progressive-web-application

I need a open source chat that is built using PWA. I tried rocketchat but the solutions in PWA are not well maintained and I need a quick solution, just in last case i can build a webapp on my own for this.

I need a solution that works offline (so the user can at least see the messages when offline).

Comment: Please give more objective details about why Rocketchat is not a solution. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to make it work like a PWA but couldn't, I need a solution that works offline (so the user can at least see the messages when offline). They even have 2 repositories that had the idea of creating a PWA of rocketchat, but they don't work and are not maintained. I need a complete solution with PWA, or else just gonna write my own app.

Comment: The offline requirement is great, please edit your question to add it, thanks!

Comment: Actually I talked with my boss today and turns out this offline matter is not going to be a problem for him, so we are going with rocketchat. I need to make some editing in the question for this?

Comment: Let's keep this question with the offline requirement, it might be useful to someone.